# SAML SSO certificates not matching but still working?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

Quick question,

Could there be any explanation for the fact that the IdP sends a certificate that is old and doesn't match the certificate that the SP expects, but SSO still works?

Could it be that the public keys somewhere else still match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen certificates where the public key doesn't change but the expiry date, serial number etc do change. This isn't common though.

The more likely scenarios are:

(i) the IdP is using the certificate expected by the SP,

(ii) the SP is using the embedded certificate,

(iii) the SP isn't verifying the signature.

If you take a look at the received SAML response it normally includes the base-64 encoded certificate embedded in the XML signature.

You can check this against the certificate you are expecting.